# What is the easiest way to schedule notification based on User's Device Timezone in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am building an app where notification will be sent to user based on their appointment date and time selection. Since there are different timezones across the world, what will be the approach to trigger notification based on their exact selection of date on their timezone?

I am using firebase to store the date and time for appointment and then using it to schedule local notification, I am able to schedule notification from raw value , need to know how to construct it for users from different timezone.

Comment: Are you scheduling a local notification on their device or are you scheduling a push notification to be delivered from your server. When, in relation to the appointment time, do you want to deliver the notification?  Surely the appointment time is related to the appointment's Timezone, so can't you simply apply a delta to the appointment time?

Comment: You say you are storing "a date and time". Are you storing them as separate values.  Don't do that. Simply store a date (which includes the time) then you don't need to worry about time zones since a date is fixed point in time.